# error uploading video with paperclip-av-transcoder in rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am using paperclip-av-transcoder gem to upload video and create thumbnail for it. But uploading video is giving following error:

`gems/paperclip-av-transcoder-0.6.4/lib/paperclip/paperclip_processors/transcoder.rb:2:in 'module:Paperclip': uninitialized constant Paperclip::Processor (NameError)`.

My current version are:

```
Ruby 2.1

rails 4.1

paperclip 4.2

paperclip-av-transcoder 0.6.4
```

Anyone else having same issue.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What is your implementation? Have you set up paperclip in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution. I placed the paperclip gem above paperclip-av-transcoder in gem file and it started working.

Hope this help someone else.